# Finding the Sum of an arithmetic series when the sum of the first two terms is given and the 20 th term is 93.

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, systems-of-equations, arithmetic

$Sn$ = $\frac{n}{2}$ $[2a + d(n - 1)]$ {equation for working out the sum of an arithmetic series}

Question:
The sum of the first two terms of an arithmetic series is 1.
The 20th term is 93. Find the first term and the common difference of the series.

I have been told that I need to form linear equations and solve simultaneously but I don't know what the n is for sum of the first two terms part.

Thank You and Help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Let the Arithmetic Progression be $a,a+d,a+2d,...$

It is given that the sum of first two terms is $1$.
$$\Longrightarrow a+(a+d)=1$$
$$\Longrightarrow 2a+d=1\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ …(1)$$
Also given that the $20th$ term is $93$. Apply the formula for the $n^{th}$ term of AP.
$$\Longrightarrow a+19d=93\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ …(2)$$
Now, $(1)$ and $(2)$ are the linear equations which you have been told to solve simultaneously. After solving, you will get $$a=-2$$
$$d=5$$
Hope it helps:)

Answer (score 0):

The "one-and-a-halfth" term is $\frac12$, and the $20$th term is $93$. So the common difference is $(93-\frac12)/(20-1\frac12)$.

Answer (score 0):

First "**TWO** terms" means $n=2$.

Comment: O ye sorry i didnt realise